# How to activate maven dependency using spring profiles,

Tags: pom.xml

I want to comment out or ignore maven dependency using spring profiles. 
Can we filter out maven dependency from application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the maven profile to filter the dependency.Not sure if spring profile works. But you could set spring.active.profile according to maven profile.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>kafka-binder</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<configuration>-->
            <!--<classifier>kafka</classifier>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>rabbit-binder</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<configuration>-->
            <!--<classifier>rabbit</classifier>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```